# How do I fix a broken berimbau?

Tags: equipment, capoeira

I have a berimbau verga that has cracked at the top. I've tried to glue or tape it it back together but the wood keeps cracking apart where the leather is nailed in. Does anyone have any suggestions for repair?

Answer (score 5):

The pressure that is generated from the string (Arame) is high and constant thats why your tip keeps cracking, If the broken piece is not too big I would suggest to get rid of it and try to make a new tip. The sound won't be the same (it will be a bit higher) but it's a solution.

Comment: Do I need to do anything except saw it off beneath the cracks? I'm not terribly worried about the pitch!

Comment: Well I would use some kind of a polisher too, just to make it a clean finish. Good luck mate.